# Create a button for multiple events on every single click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I want a button named `forward` which helps the program to shift the string `O` from `Label1` to `Label2` and `Label2` to `Label3` on the next click and so on.

[image]

Comment: you dont have to use multiple events. You can get it done in a single event itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is example code for forward button, and you can do backward by yourself. hope this can help you.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        enum stringLocation : int
        {
            label1,label2, label3, label4
        }
        int location =(int) stringLocation.label1;
        string contentToMove= "0";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            location = (location+1) % 4;
            switch (location){
            case (int) stringLocation.label1:
                    label1.Text = contentToMove;
                    label2.Text = "";
                    label3.Text = "";
                    label4.Text = "";
                    break;
            case (int) stringLocation.label2:
                    label1.Text = "";
                    label2.Text = contentToMove;
                    label3.Text = "";
                    label4.Text = "";
                    break;
            case (int) stringLocation.label3:
                    label1.Text =  "";
                    label2.Text = "";
                    label3.Text = contentToMove;
                    label4.Text = "";
                    break;
            case (int)stringLocation.label4:
                    label1.Text = "";
                    label2.Text = "";
                    label3.Text = "";
                    label4.Text = contentToMove; 
                    break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = contentToMove;
            label2.Text = "";
            label3.Text = "";
            label4.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also found that you have start and stop button,so if you want to make the string moving slowly between these labels, then you need to handle timer_Tick() function to calculate the  speed, and location of a string.

Comment: @ McMillan Cheng A big thanks, your answer hits the bull's eye.